# Class not found Exception from Weblogic 9.2

Tags: java, weblogic, classnotfoundexception, java-ee-5

In my JSF project workspace, I have a Java project **A** and a Weblogic EJB project **B** that uses the Java project.

On generating the EAR I can see that the jar for Project A and B are there in the EAR as well as that of other projects in the workspace.

However, on trying to access class from A in B i am getting a class not found exception.

The Ejb Project **B** has the `managedbean/dao/ejb/delegate` and at this point the EJB is not getting called at all. The managedbean is instantiated and from another action call I am calling the method(loadWorklist) from where the offending class is called.

Is there any specific setting I am missing?

Note this is deployed as EAR in weblogic 9.2 in UNIX server.
All required jars are loaded from inside the EAR at runtime only the classes in project A is missing.

Stack trace from the error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error calling action method of component with id worklistForm:_idJsp131
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:72)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: Exception while invoking expression #{worklistManagedBean.loadWorklist}
        at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:156)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tcs/nextgen/workflow/util/WorkflowUtil
        at com.ultimatix.nextgen.worklist.managedbean.WorklistManagedBean.loadWorklist(WorklistManagedBean.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Ear structure:

```
EAR
|
|-META-INF
|-library1.jar
|-library2.jar
|-A.jar
|-B.jar
```

Since this is an existing legacy app, jars are not in APP-INF/lib.

Comment: Can you please show the structure of the EAR, and the stracktrace you're getting?

Comment: is it calling the EJB on server startup? or on some action after server startup?

Comment: I believe WebLogic expects common libraries to be in `APP-INF/lib` in the EAR. If not, you probably have to add them to the classpath in the `MANIFEST-MF` file of the jar that depends on them. If `A` and `B` are JEE modules, then the latter probably is the solution.

Comment: @NilsH So since from the project B, I am calling class of project A, i need to add the classpath in the Manifest of B? Also since the jars A.jar and B.jar are both in the same level inside the EAR, in the manifest of B do I just write A.jar?

Comment: Yes, class path entries in MANIFEST.MF are relative.

Comment: @NilsH Yes it works. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: No problem! I have added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If module `B` uses classes from module `A`, then module `A` must be declared in the class path in the `MANIFEST.MF` of module `B`. The class path entries in this file is relative, so since the modules are at the same level, you can just specifiy `A.jar`. Other common libraries can be put in `APP-INF/lib` and will be automatically added to the class path. This however, is WebLogic specific behaviour.