# Weblogic 11g Class not found exception for remote interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, classnotfoundexception, weblogic12c

Good day, I'm trying to follow some basic tutorials on EJB and trying to have them up and running on Weblogic 12c using Netbeans. Here's the [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/ejb3/ejb-tutorial-beginners/) (one of the many I've tried so far).
The problem comes when I try to deploy a EJB module that implements a remote interface, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.service.AccountServiceRemote`. I've tried adding the project to the class library but keep on getting the same error. I've read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234566/class-not-found-exception-from-weblogic-9-2) that weblogic requieres us to declare the jar in the Manifest.mf but not sure how to do so or if this will solve my current problem.

Here's how both projects are structured.

1. Sample-Client

   - Source

     - Entity

       - Customer.java
   - Service

     - AccountServiceRemote.java
2. Sample-EJB

   - Source

     - Service

       - AccountService.java (Implements AccountServiceRemote)
   - Libraries

     - Sample-Client - dist/Sample-Client.jar

Thanks for the help.

---

Comment: How are you packing your application?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and creating 2 separate project a Java Class Library for the Sample-Client module, and a Enterprise

Comment: I bumped into the problem described above. Did you find a solution?